# Retrieving data from three different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three different tables salaries, dept_managers(Department managers), and departments
the first two tables are connected through emp_no(Employee number), While the other two tables are connected through dept_no(the department number),
I want to have a query that gives me the average amount of salaries that each department has.
I tried this query but It did not work.

```
SELECTd.dept_name,dm.dept_noFROM departments d
    JOIN dept_manager dm ON dm.dept_no = d.dept_no
    JOIN(       
            SELECT AVG(salary) AS Average_salary
           FROM salaries s
           GROUP BY salary)
           ON d.emp_no = dm.emp_no
    ;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I'm missing something here but wouldn't you just join department to employees and then join salaries to employees and get the avg salary grouped by department?

```
   select d.dept_name, avg(s.salary)
        from departments d join employees e on (e.dept_no = d.dept_no)
        join salaries s on (s.emp_no = e.emp_no)
        group by d.dept_name
```

Comment: Thank You it worked, i just had to change a little things in the query because of the way the database is set up.